I don't know where I am, but I'm active in the profile
The state of the filter selection between questions and answers in the profile is not visible:



but it is on Stack Overflow:



Easy fix:
Change the class name from active to youarehere if any of those links under #post-filters and #post-sorts are active.

More free hand circles, +1!

@SEJPM Well… in the spirit of Crypto.SE, those look like elliptic curves to me. ;)

I've seen a number of sites like this and it always bugged me. I was going to see if that affected us too.

I see it's also a problem on [security.se]

Just wow, that's possibly the most admired design of the entire collection of SE sites!

Thanks for reporting, and of course we will handle this bug!

This should be fixed now.
